# melt failed to load filter and transition qtblend

Tags: filter, transition, mlt

I've installed melt from sources in Ubuntu 18.10, codename:cosmic
Everything seems to be fine but when I'm trying to play some kdenlive file I got
[producer_xml] failed to load filter "qtblend"
[producer_xml] failed to load transition "qtblend"

When I made ./configure in the installation stage, I've detected no errors regarding Qt not found.

Which is the module that contains qtblend?

Any hint is appreciated.

Regards
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if qtblend is compiled in, run:

```
melt -query filters | grep qtblend
```

QT is compiled by default unless the configure script is not able to find your installation:
https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/src/modules/qt/configure

If QT is not found during configure, it will print out the message: "- Qt not found - disabling"

Setting qt_includedir, qt_libdir, or the $QTDIR environment variable can help.

MLT has a convenience script to compile MLT and all dependencies:

https://github.com/mltframework/mlt-scripts/blob/master/build/build-melt.sh

This script can be helpful to inspect to see how it works for QT.

Comment: The configure script uses QtGui (or Qt5Gui) to detect the presence of QT. You can check if package config is reporting its presence with: pkg-config --exists 'QtGui >= 4'